# Why can unmapped SQL Server login with no role access system views?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I just noticed that the SQL Server 2012 login I created without any roles or db mapping can access the system views in master and msdb.  Is that to be expected?  If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour. All logins are a member of a server role called `public`. It has very low level access to master/tempdb.

from: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx

> Every SQL Server login belongs to the public server role. When a
>   server principal has not been granted or denied specific permissions
>   on a securable object, the user inherits the permissions granted to
>   public on that object. Only assign public permissions on any object
>   when you want the object to be available to all users. You cannot
>   change membership in public. 
> **Note:** public is implemented differently
>   than other roles. However, permissions can be granted, denied, or
>   revoked from public.